# Problem in wpf data binding

Tags: wpf, exception, data-binding, properties, onchange

I have text field that binding with int property ProductPrice and button that is disabled if I put in textbox some wrong data (e.g. number that <= 0):

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"
                 Text="{Binding ProductPrice, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}"/>

        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddProductCommand,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                Margin="2" Width="60" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Content="Add" />
```

But if I put in textbox some text then button is not disabled. I think it because property ProductPrice is not changed because was generate some exception. Herewith validation work normal. What should I do?

Comment: What happens in the "CanExecute" of your "AddProductCommand"?

Comment: `private bool CanAddNewProduct()
        {
            if (this.Product != null
                && this.Product.IsValid
                && this.IsAddProductView
                && this.ProductList != null
                && !this.ProductList.Contains(this.Product, new Comparer()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }`

Comment: Assuming that you are implementing IDataErrorInfo in your Product class, first put a debug pointer in your ProductPrice property setter and see if it is reached when you enter some text int UI TextBox, then put a debug pointer in the CanExecute code and check if that returns true \ false, then debug your this[string columnName] property whether that throws error message.

Comment: If i put in textbox wrong data (some text), setter not work, because exception was generate before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `{Binding ProductPrice Mode=TwoWay}`

BTW, which exception are thrown?

**EDIT**: Answer to the comments

I see two options which you are have:

1. Introduce `string ProductPriceValue` property (under the cover use original one of `int` type) and bind textbox to it
2. Implement `IValueConverter` and use it in binding

Just wondering why you're not using `double` type for `ProductPrice` property

Comment: `Mode=TwoWay` not helped.
Error: `System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value 'r' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=ProductPrice; DataItem='ProductViewModel' (HashCode=41182536); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: ProductViewModel.ProductPrice is string type?

Comment: No, is int. I know that. But idea is next: user put in text field some number - is normal and button will be enabled, but if user put wrong data - button will be disabled.

Comment: Thank you for good idea :) I created string property and bind it with TextBox. After that i can control exception like this:
`public string ProductPriceValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Model.ProductPrice.ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                try
                {
                    this.Model.ProductPrice = Int32.Parse(value);
                }
                catch
                {
                    this.Model.ProductPrice = 0;
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: @Roman: nice to hear. One more thing I would recomment is to use Int32.TryParse instead of Parse so you can avoid an exception in case when entered wrong number in a textbox and don't need costly try-catch block